# Anylogic Heavy 3D Animation is stopping the model animation on runtime

Tags: animation, 3d, simulation, anylogic

I am running a model with heavy 3D animation images for agents. At the beginning, the model was running fine, but then I added new agent types with 3D images (without creating any agent instances) and now when it runs the animation window just freezes, even when the model in the background keeps running. While ignoring the 3D window the model runs without any issue. Other than decreasing the size and complexity of the 3D images, is there something that can be done for making the model run bigger 3D instances? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with the "draw distance" setting in the 3D-window properties, maybe that helps.

Also, try to move the 3D window into its own agent and navigate there only when the user wants it, i.e. normal model animation shows some plots and charts on `Main` (or whatever your root agent is).

Apart from that: use simpler 3D models. Remember that the engine runs in a browser, it is not Unity :)